# Contentful Default value for field

Tags: contentful

I am trying to add the [default value extension](https://www.contentful.com/developers/marketplace/default-field-value/) in my space but im struggling to get it to work.

The thing is the extension gets added but configuring it is where im stuck.
It comes with the example enum type with some colors.
I would like to change that add some values to the instance params but im stuck there.

Im not sure what api i should call to update an existing extension of what exactly the payload should look like.

[This is the doc Im looking into](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/#/reference/ui-extensions/configuration-parameters)

I would be great if I could get an example payload to update the instance params of the extension.